# How to backup your data with hosted issue tracking?

Tags: backup, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, hosted

I'd like to use a hosted issue-tracking service, but I want to be able
to backup my data in case the service goes under.

1. Are there any hosted issue-tracking services that have a "data
   liberation" strategy and support you periodically copying your
   issue-tracking data to your local system?
2. If not, does anyone have a clever workaround for backing up your
   data using an existing hosted issue-tracking service, even if it's in
   an unsupported way?

Comment: do you have a specific issue tracker in mind, or any will do?

Comment: Just about any will do. This is a closed-source project though, so Google Code Hosting isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [FogBugz on Demand](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/IntrotoOnDemand.html). Here is a scrape right off the "Your account" screen:

> **Download Your Database:**
>   You can download your FogBugz database in
>   three different formats. The FogBugz
>   database format (schema) is documented
>   [here](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/KB/dbsetup/FogBugzSchema.html).
>
> 1. SQL Server 2000
> 2. Access – This format is temporarily unavailable
> 3. MySQL